# Trying to get property 'hostname' of non-object

Tags: laravel, routes, jwt, dingo-api

When I use php artisan api:routes I receive the following error:

> Trying to get property 'hostname_id' of non-object

I have the following code where is this error :

```
protected $user;
protected $hostname_id;

public function __construct() {
    $this->user = JWTAuth::user();
    $this->hostname_id = $this->user->hostname_id;
   }
```

I read something that `JWTAuth::user()` return null and because of that i can not het hostname_id. Maybe is another way to receive loggedIn user data from JWT token?

Comment: Hmm, you error doesn't match your code; it says "[...] property **hostname**", but you're trying to access `hostname_id`. Is that a typo or is this occurring somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I have two controllers and in another is the same code but with `$this->user->hostname`

Comment: I solved it, thanks

Comment: No problem! The solution is likely the same `$this->user` is `null`, so you can't access a property, `->example`, so either check for `null` before trying to access, or a fallback. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error happen because when you are run `php artisan api:route` it is call all controller `__constract()` function You can use this code

```
protected $user;
protected $hostname_id;

public function __construct() {
    $this->user = JWTAuth::user();
    $this->hostname_id = $this->user->hostname_id ?? null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood!